# Is it possible to define nodePort in "kubectl expose" command?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a `ReplicationController` and I expose it as a `Service` by:

`kubectl expose rc my-rc --port=9000 --target-port=8080 --type=NodePort --name=my-service`

Then, Kubernetes gives me a random public port for the exposed `Service`, 31289 for instance. If you create the `Service` using a `yaml` file, you can define that port in `spec.ports[*].nodePort` field. In this case, I have to create the `Service` via `expose` command instead of declaratively using a `yaml`.

Is there a way to define the `nodePort` in `kubectl expose` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to specify a NodePort when creating a service of type `NodePort`. Feel free to file a [feature request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/new) to add this feature (or send a pull request).